# SQLite convert every value in a column except for one

Tags: sql, sqlite

My last column by mistake contains either 1's or 2's instead of 1 or 0...
how could i convert all 2's to 0's?

Comment: `Update myTable SET LastColumn = 0 WHERE LastColumn = 2`

Comment: thank you very much sir!

Comment: @oxygen You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `update` statement with a `where` clause to affect only rows with `2`s.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    mycolumn = 0
WHERE  mycolumn = 2
```